# file_put_content() method not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
function put()
    {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Website_Name = '$GLOBALS[str]'") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<div id='container' style='width:100%'>
<style>
h1 {font-size:45px;}
</style>
<div id='header' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>
<h1 style='margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;height:20%;float:center;'>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>
<table align='left'><tr><td><img src="$row[Website_Name]/index.jpg" align='center' width='240' height='170'></td></tr></table>
<table align='center'><br><tr><td><h1>"$row[Business_Name]"</td></tr></table>
<?php
}
 ?>

file_put_contents("'$GLOBALS[str]'/index.php",put());
```

i am using file_put_contents() method.. but its not writing the data into the file.

Answer (score 1):

Because your function `put` does not ***`return`*** any data. It writes text to the output, but it does not `return` anything. Hence nothing is written to the file. Learn about function return values here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Furthermore I'd think `"'$GLOBALS[str]'/index.php"` is not a valid filename.

Answer (score 0):

$data = "your data";

$file = uniqid().'.php';  //if you dont want to create file, you can use your existing file.

$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);